# Google Enhanced ecommerce purchasing not logged

Tags: google-analytics, enhanced-ecommerce

I am absolutely not enable to get Enhanced e-commerce working.

Please do not send be google tutorials I went like 10 times over them. (Please send me some tutorials for absolute dumb people how to set it really step by by step)

I am using a debugger and not seeing a thing.

NOTE: I can see a page view inside Google Analytics. But adding a item to a cart or purchasing a transaction I can not see inside Google analytics UI.

```html
<head>
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1', 'auto'); // this is hidden UA
ga('send', 'pageview'); /*FIRST PAGE VIEW CALLED HERE */
ga('require', 'ec');

ga('ec:addProduct', {               // Provide product details in an productFieldObject.
  'id': 'P12345',                   // Product ID (string).
  'name': 'Android Warhol T-Shirt', // Product name (string).
  'category': 'Apparel',            // Product category (string).
  'brand': 'Google',                // Product brand (string).
  'variant': 'black',               // Product variant (string).
  'price': '29.20',                 // Product price (currency).
  'coupon': 'APPARELSALE',          // Product coupon (string).
  'quantity': 1                     // Product quantity (number).
});

ga('ec:setAction', 'purchase', {          // Transaction details are provided in an actionFieldObject.
  'id': 'T12345',                         // (Required) Transaction id (string).
  'affiliation': 'Google Store - Online', // Affiliation (string).
  'revenue': '37.39',                     // Revenue (currency).
  'tax': '2.85',                          // Tax (currency).
  'shipping': '5.34',                     // Shipping (currency).
  'coupon': 'SUMMER2013'                  // Transaction coupon (string).
});
ga('send', 'pageview');   
</script>
</head>
```

This si example from their tutorial. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#measuring-transactions
I have got this code inside my head attribute.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Why do you have two page views? They examples you link to show only one. Also did you enable enhanced e-commerce in the config?

Comment: Did you have enabled enhanced ecommerce tracking in your view settings in GA? Can you track other product actions apart from `purchase`?

Comment: According to the two page views, I saw it somewhere and it should not really matter.  Yes I have ecommerce tracking enabled in GA. No I can not track any other actions, I was able to track only impressions

Comment: Your code looks fine as I can copy and paste it (after changing property ID) and I can see the hit go through. I would still remove the first pageview as you are inflating your PVs by sending it twice. Remove the first one. Are you also waiting at least 24 hours for the data to be processed?

Comment: It's working now, I had to wait 24 hours. There was not hint that I should do that so... ok THX

Comment: Cool, good to know.